# What is cloudant document expiration field?

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant

Is document expiration field set with date-time or seconds or milliseconds?
As I know it's seconds:

```
"expiration": 1543086426,
```

So `1543086426 = Saturday, November 24, 2018 7:07:06 PM`

Then why the document is being removed by Cloudant?
If it's milliseconds then:

```
1543086426 =  Sunday 18 January 1970 12:38:06
```

that explains. So how do I set proper expiration value for cloudant document e.g. in 1 month from now?

Also, which Cloudant task is responsible for document removal? And how often it starts?

Comment: What are you referring to?

Comment: the documents periodically removed from cloudant. So my question: do I set expiration field correct? is it milliseconds or seconds? Or should be date-time format

Comment: I don't think Cloudant supports expiration of documents. Is there an external process using the expiration field to remove the documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the CouchDB document

> Time to live (TTL) is the amount of time until a document expires in
>   Couchbase Server. By default, all documents have a TTL of zero, which
>   indicates the document is kept indefinitely. Typically when you add,
>   set, or replace information, you establish a custom TTL by passing it
>   as a parameter to your method call. As part of normal maintenance
>   operations, Couchbase Server periodically removes all items with
>   expiration times that have passed.
>
> Depending on the amount of time you want to specify for the document
>   to live, you provide a TTL value as a relative number of seconds into
>   the future or in Unix time . Unix time represents a specific date and
>   time expressed as the number of seconds that have elapsed since
>   Thursday, 1 January 1970 at 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)
>   . For example, the value 1421454149 represents Saturday, 17 January
>   2015 at 00:22:29 UTC.

But, Cloudant does not support Time to Live functions.

The reason is that IBM Cloudant documents are only 'soft' deleted, not deleted. The soft deletion involves replacing the original document with a smaller record. This small record or 'tombstone' is required for replication purposes; it helps ensure that the correct revision to use can be identified during replication.

If the TTL capability was available in IBM Cloudant, the resulting potential increase in short-lived documents and soft deletion records would mean that the database size might grow in an unbounded fashion.

For more info, refer this [link on TTL](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/document.html#ttl-time-to-live)